# replace substring by searching the pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this date time below

```
Wed Jun 13 2018 21:08:29 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

and 21.08.29 can be any string depending on what time the user selecting data. I want replace this 21:08:29 with 11:59:59 so the output should be.

```
Wed Jun 13 2018 11:59:59 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Any ideas,

Comment: here's an idea - use string replace method with a regular expression that looks for numbers colon numbers colon numbers - why do you want the time to be a second before midday?

Comment: @Kim2018 Is the original object - Date? if yes, why don't you try to set the time factor instead of parsing string and then changing time.

Comment: that's a better idea :p

Comment: I think the simplest way is to break down the whole string into 3pieces and replace the 2nd piece with 11:59:59

Comment: Thanks CuriousMind - Using set time is good in this case

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for you to resolve it by regex

```
var originalText = 'Wed Jun 13 2018 21:08:29 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)';
var replacedText =  originalText.replace(/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/,'11:59:59');
```

[0-9] - Any number

{2} - length of string of [0-9]

If however your string was a Date type variable or can be stored in a date type variable

```
var newVar = new Date( 'Jun 13 2018 21:08:29 GMT-0700');
newVar.setHours(11);
newVar.setMinutes(59);
newVar.setSeconds(59);
```

would give `Jun 13 2018 11:59:59 GMT-0700`
would also do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Regular Expression?

```
var str = /*(DateTime string)*/;
var _regex = [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2};

var newstr = str.replace(_regex, /*(Time what you want)*/);
```

BUT, the string you provided seems like `Date` object, so consider using member functions of it.

this might helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for 24 hours with mandatory leading 0:

```
var newvalue='11:59:59';
Var str='Wed Jun 13 2018 21:08:29 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)';
var replacedStrign=str.replace(/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/, newvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the string to a date object, manipulate that date object, then convert back to a string.

```
const time = new Date("Wed Jun 13 2018 21:08:29 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)")
time.setHours(11)
time.setMinutes(59)
time.setSeconds(59)
time.toString() // "Wed Jun 13 2018 11:59:59 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)"
```

Edit: I realized this solution loses the timezone information but still might be a useful approach in certain situations.